# What kind of optimization would increase my performance?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, optimization

I wrote a small java program which benchmarks sorting algorithms(merge sort, selection sort) and displays the time they need to sort person-objects (name, ascending).

The C++ version of this program is at least 4 times slower than the java version. There are several developers who said that they beat java in sorting by optimizing their code. Release mode, /O2, 64 bit, ... . I have already done those tweaks.

Is there any inefficiency in my sorting algorithm (especially merge sort)?

```
//create a subvector
template <typename T> std::vector<T> splitVec(std::vector<T> main, size_t from, size_t to) {

std::vector<T>::const_iterator first = main.begin() + from;
std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = main.begin() + to;
std::vector<T> erg(first, last);

return erg;
}

//merge sort - sorting process
template <typename T> std::vector<T> merge(std::vector<T> m1, std::vector<T> m2) {

unsigned int posA = 0, posB = 0;

std::vector<T> erg;

while (posA < m1.size() && posB < m2.size()) {
    if (m1.at(posA).compareTo(m2.at(posB)) <= 0) {
        erg.push_back(m1.at(posA));
        posA++;
    }
    else {
        erg.push_back(m2.at(posB));
        posB++;
    }
}

while (posA < m1.size()) {
    erg.push_back(m1.at(posA));
    posA++;
}

while (posB < m2.size()) {
    erg.push_back(m2.at(posB));
    posB++;
}

return erg;
}

//merge sort-split up vectors
template <typename T> std::vector<T> mergeSort(std::vector<T> pers) {

if (pers.size() > 1) {

    //Split pers into two equally sized vectors
    std::vector<T> p1(splitVec(pers, 0, pers.size()/2));
    std::vector<T> p2(splitVec(pers, (pers.size()/2), pers.size()));

    return merge(mergeSort(p1), mergeSort(p2));
}
else
    return pers;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Pass argument by (const-)reference instead of by value to avoid extra copies.

Comment: you are passing and returning vectors by value. In C++ this copies all elements of the vector.

Comment: Optimizations in the code structure usually beat compiler optimization settings. Passing the vectors by reference instead of by value would be a good first step. [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)ing the required amount of space up front an easy second. Those two alone should put you into the same ballpark as Java, at the minimum. To be fair, at least you didn't `new` every object, so there's hope. ;-)

Comment: minor: `at` does bound check whereas `[]` doesn't (and you already check index validity :-) ).

Comment: Also, find the costly paths in your code by profiling - then you can go about optimizing things in a targeted fashion.

Comment: I have passed everything by reference and reserved space everywhere I could. My program works much faster now :)

Comment: The c++ version outperforms the java version drastically. :)))

Comment: @TalipVural this is what we love to hear.

Comment: Do you want me to delete while(...) @Jarod42 ?

Comment: @TalipVural: No, I mean that as you use valid index in range (it is not a input which might be invalid), so you may use directly `m1[posA]` and `m2[posB]` instead of `m1.at(posA)` and `m2.at(posB)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the vector by reference. This should improve performance significantly.

When you pass the vector by value you copy it every time (adding complexity of O(n) in every step)

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass the vector around. Not by value, and not by reference. Pass iterators:

```
template <class Iter>
void sort(Iter first, Iter last) {
    ...
}

sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end();
```

To split a range, just calculate the middle value:

```
template <class Iter>
Iter mid(Iter first, Iter last) {
    return first + (last - first) / 2;
}
```

This assumes that the code is still sorting values held in some sort of container (in the original code, a `std::vector`), so the iterators are random-access iterators.

Comment: I will try but I have never heard of iterators.

Comment: @TalipVural - iterators are part of the STL trilogy: iterators, algorithms, containers. They're the underpinning for much of the power of the C++ standard library. It will be well worth the effort to dig into that subject. [Here's a link](https://cal-linux.com/tutorials/STL.html) to a tutorial that I just looked up. Don't know if it's any good, but a quick glance showed that it has some promise.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the source data by reference, rather than copying it, would be a huge improvement.

In addition, you should `reserve` space in `erg`, otherwise you're repeatedly re-allocating and copying all the elements as you add more.

Comment: does it really result in copying all the elements?

Comment: @tobi303 If the new element does not fit into the space that is currently allocated, all elements are reallocated to a new location in memory.

Comment: @tobi303: Yes, it really does.

Comment: makes sense, as the elements are stored contiguously, but somehow I was not aware of that

Answer (score 1):

Using push_back instead of indexing is slow. A one time allocation of a working array or vector, and indexing into that array eliminates doing all those recursive allocations. Using a pair of mutually recursive functions eliminates having to copy data back after a merge.

A bottom up merge sort would be slightly faster, and while bottom up merge sorts are normally what are used by most libraries (such as std::stable_sort), top down merge sort seems to be what is taught in class rooms.

Example template for a top down merge sort that will work for an array or vector (pass the vector as a pointer to the first element).

```
template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
template <typename T>
void TopDownMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee);

template <typename T>
void MergeSort(T a[], size_t n)             // entry function
{
    if(n < 2)                               // if size < 2 return
        return;
    T *b = new T[n];
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    delete[] b;
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1)                  // if size == 1 return
        return;
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
    TopDownMerge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);     // merge b to a
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1){                 // if size == 1 copy a to b
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        return;
    }
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
    TopDownMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);     // merge a to b
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index
    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)                   //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr)                   //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will discuss your version with my teacher. Why do you pass the array size? Couldn't you just fetch it with array.size() ?

Comment: In C / C++, arrays don't have a size. A vector has a size, but this template is designed for arrays, so for a vector, a pointer to the first element and the size of the vector (number of elements) are passed as parameters to MergeSort()..

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing a very big optimization.  You are passing all of the vectors by value instead of by reference.  This means every function call is copying the vectors which is very inefficient.

Since everything in java is a pointer your java code is not going to be making all of these copies which should be a major part of the slowdown in the C++ code.